# web service getting started

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have to implement a web service in my work, the problem is that I don't have any idea what a web services is.
Can you give me some references to get started and to understand what people are asking me for?
Maybe some good book also ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Started with basics about a web service [here](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp)

Assuming you want to use WCF to build web services read about it more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480190.aspx)  or if you want to use legacy web services with .net read [here](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebservices/DotNetWebServices.asp)

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWebService.aspx) is a simple wcf service application with code which you can build on further and understand.

Answer (score 1):

[Start at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webservices)

Also some great info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There simply isn't a short answer to this question, but there are limitless guides you can easily find on any search engine to help you get started.  But since you asked, here are two links, one to help you understand the inner-workings of a web service, and the second, a guide to creating your first service in ASP.NET

[Anatomy of a Web Service: XML, SOAP and WSDL for Platform-independent Data Exchange](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/web_service/)

[Create Your First ASP.NET Web Service](http://www.webreference.com/programming/asp_net/web_service/)