# Online sqlserver and security against reflection

Tags: vb.net, security, reflector, activation

I am planning to use an online activation for my winform application. 
I plan to us a MySQL database for it.

The thing I am worried about is if someone tries to Reflect the code(Ex: Redgate .Net Reflector) they will be able to see the connection string and connect to the database.

Is there any better way to secure the online activation?

Comment: Create a web service instead and hide the database behind that.

Comment: thanks,
Can you guide to any reference site where i can learn about it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408823/web-service-getting-started I suggest a RESTFUL one, since this is where the world is going, it seems. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor

Comment: OK, I did some research and I have a doubt.

What if the one who is supposedly using reflection on my software tries to access my methods(using his own software) within the services to get the key?